# How should I convert array of base64 string to zip file in C# ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: file, base64, zip, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to provide a `.zip` file to Angular for download, I have list of base64 strings need to convert it to zip and provide back to Angular for download there.

I have tried by using `zipArchive` and `archive.CreateEntry`, but I'm not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
        [HttpGet("test")]
        public IActionResult test()
        {
            var byteStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my string");
            var bs64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(byteStr);

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bs64Str);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);     
            return File(ms, "application/zip", "downloadedbase64.zip");
        }
```

[image]